# Keep getting _getReadAdapter and _getWriteAdapter error

Tags: magento

I tried to create a custom resource model collection. The code is pretty simple like below. But I keep getting this error:

**Fatal error: Class Namespace_ModuleName_Model_Resource_History contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract::_getReadAdapter, Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract::_getWriteAdapter) in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\community\Namespace\ModuleName\Model\Resource\History.php on line 10**

Line 10 is basically the close curve bracket } sign. What could be wrong?

```
<!--config.xml-->
    <models>
        <modulename>
            <class>Namespace_ModuleName_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>modulename_resource</resourceModel>
        </modulename>
        <modulename_resource>
            <class>Namespace_ModuleName_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <history>
                    <table>table_name_history</table>
                </history>
            </entities>
        </modulename_resource>
    </models>

//app\code\community\Namespace\ModuleName\Model\History.php
class Namespace_ModuleName_Model_History extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('modulename/history');
    }   

}


//app\code\community\Namespace\ModuleName\Model\Resource\History.php
class Namespace_ModuleName_Model_Resource_History extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract {

    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('modulename/history','history_id');

    }   

}


//app\code\community\Namespace\ModuleName\Model\Resource\History\Collection.php
class Namespace_ModuleName_Model_Resource_History_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract {

    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('modulename/history');
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't look too deeply at your entire module structure, and don't have a Magento system to reference at the moment, but I'm pretty sure the base resource model class you want to extend is `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract`, and not `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract`.

Comment: Now I get Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract' not found

Comment: @user2880076 Maybe that's because you're extending the wrong class again?  Try reading up on models/resources/collections  http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics

Comment: I get that error when extending to Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract like you suggested. If I extend to Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract, I get the original error above.

Comment: @user2880076 You're seeing the new error because you're also extending the wrong collection class.  It's a second error, unrelated to the first, which has been fixed.

Comment: You're right. Now I'm extending to Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract. But now I get **Fatal error: Call to a member function getConnection() on a non-object**

Comment: @user2880076 As I said, it sounds like you need to review how to setup models, resources, and collections at the above link.  Good luck!